# Target and Board for a C embedded Program with Arcom in Keil

Tags: c, embedded, clang

Good day everyone,

Please be kind an encouraging, as I am beginner in Embedded Programming, even if I have strong knowledge in C/C++.

Michael Barr, in his book, *Programming Embedded Systems*, writes, page 17, that "this function is specific to Arcom's Target188EB board.

I have Keil uVision 5 installed on my machine with Windows.

And I went in package installer to see if I can find , at least, the installer for simulating programs of the book. But I did not find the installer.

Why?

In particular, there is a special piece of code :

```
asm{
 mov dx, P2LTCH
 in a1, dx

 ....
}
```

which is special for this board.

So, I guess I should have the hardware, or at least the possibility ton download the package that fits to this board to be able to make the simulation.

Do you know why I don't find Arcom's Target188EB board in the package installer list ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The board you refer to is an obsolete antique with an equally obsolete Intel 80188 processor on board.  Keil do not produce a tool chain to target that.
2. Assembler code is architecture specific - that code is meaningless on anything that is not an 16 bit 8086 based processor.
3. In-line assembler syntax is compiler specific - you'd need the tool chain used for the original code to be sure it would compile in any case.   Borland C++ 3.1 apparently (also an antique).

The [code you are referring](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/Books/Programming-Embedded-Systems/Your-First-Embedded-Program) to uses the GPIO I/O port referred to by P2LTCH to control an LED.  On other more modern and readily available boards, the method of accessing GPIO to flash an LED will differ.  That is not fundamental perhaps to what the book is trying to teach you, but a more up-to-date book might be in order, or you need to know enough to be able to apply the content of the book to other systems - that is you need to be able to *generalise* the information using other resources perhaps.

Any board directly supported by the Keil tools generally has a "Blinky" app - the embedded world's answer to "Hello, World!", which does exactly what this exercise in Barr's book is exemplifying.  Its purpose is to flash an LED to verify that you can build, load and execute code that can access the hardware.

I suggest you obtain a modern board directly supported by your toolchain, and supported by a broad community.  Any number of ARM based microcontroller boards are available for very low cost, and much higher performance that the Arcom board and a broader peripheral set than